# Control usb PTZ camera in a browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webrtc, zooming, pan, tilt

I have a Logitech PTZ USB camera. I have prepared a video call functionality using WebRtc. Now what I need is to add Pan, Tilt and Zoom controls within the browser so user can controls the camera based on his need.

Is it possible to implement PTZ control using JavaScript/WebRtc or any other third-party JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott Hanselman wrote a PTZ controller for the Logitech cameras back in 2012: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/CloudControlledRemotePanTiltZoomCameraAPIForALogitechBCC950CameraWithAzureAndSignalR.aspx

The APIs needed for that are not available to Javascript sadly.

Comment: Thank you Philipp, the code works for Logitech PTZ USB camera, only the issue is, it does not returns PanTilt values.